# How to fetch data from two related to each other endpoints Using RTK-Query

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have two endpoints:

`GET /api/messages/:userId/latest` and
`GET /api/messages/:userId/:page`

When the application loads a screen then, it calls the first endpoint to get information which pages have to loaded for a specific users, for example:

```js
{
   pages: [324, 325, 326]
}
```

and then, the second endpoint is called several times with parameters taken from the first endpoint.

My question is: How to define a query in Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query which calls the endpoints in this way and then merges the results?

My code snippets:

```js
export interface MessageApiParams {
  userId: String | undefined,
  page: number
}

export const baseQuery = fetchBaseQuery({
  baseUrl: '/api',
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    const token = getAccessToken()?.token
    if (token) {
      headers.set("authorization", `Bearer ${token}`);
    }
    return headers;
  },
})

export const messagesApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'messagesApi',
  baseQuery: baseQuery,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getMessages: builder.query<Messages, MessageApiParams>({
      query: (params: MessageApiParams) => {
        return ({
          url: `/users/${params.userId}/messages/${params.page}`,
          method: 'GET',
          headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${getAccessToken()?.token}`}
        });
      }
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Dont think it's possible using query, but i'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine [multiple requests in a single custom query function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#performing-multiple-requests-with-a-single-query).

Example could look something like the following:

```js
export interface MessageApiParams {
  userId: String | undefined;
}

export interface MessagesApiResult {
  pages: number[];
  messages: MessageOrError[];
}
```

```js
export const messagesApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'messagesApi',
  baseQuery,
  endpoints: builder => ({
    getMessages: builder.query<MessagesApiResult, MessageApiParams>({
      queryFn: async(
        { userId }: MessageApiParams,
        api,
        extraOptions,
        baseQuery
      ) => {
        // Fetch latest messages from endpoint #1 "/api/messages/:userId/latest"
        const messagesResult = await baseQuery({
          url: `/messages/${userId}/latest`,
          method: 'GET',
        });

        if (messagesResult.error) {
          return {
            error: messagesResult.error as /* your base query error type here */
          };
        }

        const pages = messagesResult as number[];

        // Fetch pages from endpoint #2 "/api/messages/:userId/:page"
        const pagesResults = await Promise.all(pages.map(
          page => baseQuery({
            url: `/messages/${userId}/${page}`,
            method: 'GET',
          })
        ));

        return {
          data: {
            pages,
            messages: pagesResults
          } as MessagesApiResult;
        };
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```